# SQL Server stored procedure summing one field with parameter input from C#

Tags: sql, sql-server

Stored procedure has multiple functions.

Step One: I need to retrieve an `int` from a table, `SUM` it with an `@int` variable that is user entered. Then store that value back into the same column it was retrieved from. I.E. We have one, we order one, add one because we now have two because that item is already in inventory.

Here's what I have so far:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TotalOnHand INT;     

SELECT  (
    Select Sum(TotalOnHand)
    FROM (Values (InvTotalQtyOnHand), (@InvTotalQtyOnHand)) as TSum(TotalOnHand)
)
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum On PartManufPartNum = InvManPartNumber
WHERE POItemsID = @POItemsID
UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
SET InvTotalQtyOnHand = @TotalOnHand

END
```

When ran I see the InvTotalQtyOnHand now = 2 (there was one in the column and user entered 1 = 2 in the qry results window

Error I get:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'InvTotalQtyOnHand', table 'TrackLinq.dbo.InventoryMaster_tbl'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Obviously `InvTotalQtyOnHand` becomes `Null` since `@TotalOnHand = null`

First post here so be nice. I've researched this site for years... I know how it can be... :) I hope I was concise enough for you all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need a blank line to get that BEGIN to be part of the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't assign value to `@TotalOnHand` so the value is `null`. You can do it in a following way.

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TotalOnHand INT;  --newly declared, not assigned. NULL   

SELECT  @TotalOnHand = (
    Select Sum(TotalOnHand)
    FROM (Values (InvTotalQtyOnHand), (@InvTotalQtyOnHand)) as TSum(TotalOnHand)
)
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum On PartManufPartNum = InvManPartNumber
WHERE POItemsID = @POItemsID

UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
SET InvTotalQtyOnHand = @TotalOnHand -- now assigned
--you forget filter. All rows will be updated
where <some condition>

END
```

In fact you don't need first `select` statement. You can do `update` directly.

```
UPDATE [InventoryMaster_tbl]
SET InvTotalQtyOnHand = InvTotalQtyOnHand + @InvTotalQtyOnHand --comes from SP parameters
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum On PartManufPartNum = InvManPartNumber
WHERE POItemsID = @POItemsID --comes from SP parameters
```

Comment: As my son says (he's 16) awesome sauce! That was it, more importantly for me is I understand. This is a qry that has multiple conditions. I appreciate the assistance and the respect instead of well DA did you look here? I truly spend one hell of a lot of time before I ask. Thank you again. How do I give you, questioned answered and credit?

Answer (score 0):

The columns **InvTotalQtyOnHand** is not null column which means which will not allow nulls. So, you can check if the @TotalOnHand is null, if yes then try inserting zero instead of null to the column. Refer [ISNULL (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) as below

```
Update [InventoryMaster_tbl]
Set InvTotalQtyOnHand = ISNULL(@TotalOnHand,0)
```

Your script can be like below,

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @TotalOnHand INT;     
SELECT  
(Select Sum(TotalOnHand)
FROM (Values (InvTotalQtyOnHand), (@InvTotalQtyOnHand)) as Sum(TotalOnHand))
FROM InventoryMaster_tbl
INNER JOIN PurchaseOrderItems_tbl PartManufPartNum On PartManufPartNum =   InvManPartNumber
WHERE POItemsID = @POItemsID

Update [InventoryMaster_tbl]
Set InvTotalQtyOnHand = ISNULL(@TotalOnHand,0)

END
```

Comment: Probably should have stated column/field defaults on first post. InvTotalQtyOnHand Allow nulls = no Default value = 0  InvManPartNumber = non-clusterindex = yes. "field must be unique" InvTotalQtyOnHand